# analytics api oauth2callback redirect in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-analytics

I have an issue in codeigniter trying to do this example:

[Hello Analytics API: PHP quickstart for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php)

Always is redirecting to the auth page

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code
```

I think that the problem is that I can't get the code : `$_GET['code']`

in the file oauth2callback.php(see the example file in the link)

```
I tried $_GET['code'] and $this->input->get('code')

and tried in the config 

$config['enable_query_strings']     = TRUE;

and 

$config['enable_query_strings']     = FALSE;
```

I don't know what else to try.

Thanks

Comment: I found the solution :)   to get de code  must write       $url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);    parse_str($url['query'], $params);  and $code = $params['code'];   and replace $_GET['code'] with $code  or $params['code']

Comment: Put your solution as an answer; after a while you can accept that answer, which marks the problem as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :) to get de code must write

$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
parse_str($url['query'], $params);

and $code = $params['code'];

must replace $_GET['code'] with $code or $params['code']

maybe this is useful for someone ^_^